# Django - Responder con JsonResponse y pdf

Tags: python, django

Tengo una view que responde con un JsonResponse. Necesito generar un reporte en pdf usando la misma instancia de la clase Building (la variable estructura).

Por ejemplo, la view que retorna un Json es:

```
   @login_required
    def buildings(request):
        if request.POST and request.is_ajax():
            s_form = BuildingForm(request.POST)
            if s_form.is_valid():
                structure = Building(**s_form.cleaned_data)
                html = render_to_string('wind/results/buildings/buildings_results.html', {'structure': structure})
                return JsonResponse({"result": html})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'building_errors': s_form.errors,
                                    status=400)
        else:
            s_form = BuildingForm()
            return render(request, 'wind/buildings.html', {'s_form': s_form})
```

Tengo el siguiente codigo para generar y retornar el pdf:

```
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Report.pdf"'
    buffer = BytesIO()
    report = BuildingsReport(structure)  # Quiero usar la misma instancia
    pdf = report.generate_pdf()
    response.write(pdf)
    return response
```

Lo que quiero es usar la misma instancia para generar tanto como el html y el pdf.

Usar una view diferente implicaria hacer otra instancia de la clase Building, excepto que haya alguna otra solución haciendo otra view que yo desconozca.

En el navegador quisiera que se muestre el html con los resultados y un boton disponible para el usuario para descargar el pdf cuando el quiera.

He leido algo de Celery, pero no termino de entender o descubrir si es adecuado para hacer algo asi.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: No puedes generar dos respuestas al tiempo, si conoces el funcionamiento básico de http debes saber que a una petición le corresponde una respuesta, por lo que debes buscar otra forma de llamar el archivo de pdf, ya sea enviando un parámetro por GET que te diga cuando va a enviar en pdf o html, y dar respuesta de acuerdo a eso, así por defecto retornas el html, y cuando click en un botón que vuelva a enviar los datos al servidor pero con el parámetro para dar la respuesta en pdf, igual no estás guardando nada actualmente en la base de datos con el proceso

Comment: Si, es cierto. Tengo la opción de guardar la instancia como diccionario en la sesión de Django, pero por ahora lo veo complicado porque tengo algunas arrays de numpy en diccionarios anidados. Esto me complica porque las arrays no son serializables. Podría pasarlas a listas con el método "tolist()" pero por ahora lo vengo evitando. De todos modos estoy investigando a ver si puedo hacerlo asincronicamente con Celery.

Comment: Es que con Celery no veo que logres lo que quieres hacer, porque básicamente quieres dar respuesta a una petición que no fue hecha, y http no funciona así. La solución que te planteo, es para que evites crear otra vista haciendo lo mismo que tienes que hacer en esta y así no tener que pasar los datos por sesión que esto puede producir más errores

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. En ese caso veo que no queda otra que calcular dos veces los resultados, una para mostrar el html y la otra para calcular el pdf cuando se solicitado.

Comment: Igual, pensando en que pudieras hacerlo, cómo crees que podrías almacenar el archivo en pdf desde el html hasta que el usuario lo quisiera descargar? Porque la etiqueta `<object>` hace peticiones, y no tendrías que hacer el content-disposition con `attachment` si no con `inline`

Comment: Estaba pensando que quizas desde otra vista sería lo mas viable. Ya que de todos modos tengo que calcular nuevamente los resultados. Todavia hay conceptos que no tengo muy claros, estoy empezando con Django y se van presentando problemas.